# Module not found: Can't resoulve *.d.ts in "/file/path" in React TypeScript bootstrap with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and likes to separate my type definition from my code so I created a `*.d.ts` file but the exported TS definition cannot be imported and use on other module file

```
Module not found: Can't resoulve *.d.ts in "/file/path"
```

would someone recommended a fix or explanation why this happen ?

[image]

Comment: You import the "InputTupe", "Marketing" and other components from the wrong path "../drafts", because there is no draft directory in your component structure.

Comment: @novonimo I swear I didn't I double check all export, import as well as  the file structure. The screenshot of the Image shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found in my case is that if you import something from `*.d.ts`. If your file is name `data.d.ts` you can import it like this.

```js
import { testA } from data.d
```

notice the `data.d` from which the name of the file that you want to import is `data.d.ts`